# Can't access GitHub via Google Chrome?

Tags: 16.04, networking, google-chrome, github

I successfully run the command `ping github.com`. Output is like:

```
PING github.com (192.30.253.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=38 time=227 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=38 time=232 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=3 ttl=38 time=221 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=4 ttl=38 time=233 ms
```

But when I try to open it via Chrome it gets stuck at

> establishing secure connection

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache and cookies? is internet connection strong?

Comment: I tried, it will connect but after some attempts were unsuccessful. Yes the internet is good.

Comment: changing your dns to googles might help by adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` as the first line in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Are you able to access it via another browser, like firefox?

Comment: I'm able to  reproduce the issue ... so I think question should stay open. works fine on Firefox but chromium can't open it. mine says: "github.com took too long to respond."

Comment: I've tried that @ptetteh227

Comment: No I can't @jrg

Comment: Same issue here. I can connect trough firefox but not with chrome. At Jul-2019

Comment: Is this still valid? I cannot reproduce with recent chrome.. and 16.04.5 ubuntu.

Comment: @TadejP, not valid anymore, at least for me.